# Radius Networks can't locate iBeacon with Android

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon

Yesterday my RadBeacons TAGs received. I can locate the Beacons by using the iOS app Locate and RadBeacon. The but I can't locate the Beacons with Locate app for Android. In addition I can't locate beacons with a simple app I developed myself.
I am developing with Eclipse and I followed this instruction: http://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com/docs/android/getting-started

Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: The Android Locate app can't run because that app will only detect AltBeacons. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

RadBeacon tag model currently only transmits an iBeacon advertisement.  The Locate app for Android as well as the ProximityKit library for Android will only detect AltBeacon advertisements by default, due to intellectual property issues.

The solution is to either use RadBeacon USB units that transmit both an iBeacon and an AltBeacon advertisement, or look for third party instructions for configuring Android Locate or the ProximityKit Android library to detect proprietary beacon advertisements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yesterday Radius Networks annouced a rerelease of the Android Proximity Kit SDK what about this? Can this SDK help me to detect Ibeacons with an Android device? And is it not possible to use the a BeaconParser in addition with the AltBeacon?

Comment: The Proximity Kit SDK is built on top of the open source Android Beacon Library, so yes, the BeaconParser class may be used to make the Proximity Kit SDK work with proprietary beacon types.